# Easiest way to execute command and output its result

Tags: c++, command-line, terminal, multiplatform

I'm working on a C++ console application. What is the easiest (ideally multiplatform) way to call a system command and output its result right into the console?

I know there's the `system()` but it's impossible to redirect it to `cout` right?

Then there's `popen` (on Windows `_popen`) but it's a whole lot more complex to call. Instead of a one-liner as with `system`, you have to have a buffer, loop through a file etc.

As a C++ newbie I don't understand what exactly to do and why is it so difficult.

Comment: What's actually wrong with `system()` for your case? You usually don't need an explicit redirect.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the output of the command in your C++ program?

Comment: Oh crap, my bad. I was redirecting `stdout` to a file at the same time. That's why I didn't see any output 

Comment: I've got `freopen("out.txt","w",stdout);` in the beginning of my file. How do I stop the redirect before calling `system`?

Comment: `system()` is a security nightmare. Don't use it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The program is for personal use only. I don't really need to care about security that much.

Comment: @m93a: If it's just for personal use, then why should it be multiplatform anyway?

Comment: Because in this case it's a homework for programming class and our teacher uses linux, so that he'd be also able to compile it. Furthermore I also switch between OSes and want to be able to work on my HW without caring about what platform I'm on. I don't have to care about different commands on different platforms, because `gnuplot` (the library we use) is the same on both Windows and linux.

Comment: On Windows you would typically use createpipe and createprocess. Look them up in MSDN